# Cloudinary upload php failed, how to fix it?

Tags: php, html, cloudinary

I try using cloudinary for upload my image and video for my personal blog but it's a fail. I watch this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZCQLjfq97o. the error says :

> Notice: Undefined index: file in >C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\index.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in >C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\index.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Cloudinary\Error: Missing required parameter - file in C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Uploader.php:558 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Uploader.php(407): Cloudinary\Uploader::call_api('upload', Array, Array, NULL) #1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Uploader.php(100): Cloudinary\Uploader::call_cacheable_api('upload', Array, Array, NULL) #2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\index.php(11): Cloudinary\Uploader::upload(NULL, Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp7\htdocs\lovantoBlog\cloudinary\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Uploader.php on line 558

This is my code for upload :

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['Simpan'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $slug = $_POST['slug'];
    $gambar = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($file_tmp, array('public_id' => $slug));
}
```

and this is the code for form :

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nama">
    <input type="text" name="slug">
    <?php echo cl_image_upload_tag('image_id');?>
    <input type="submit" name="Simpan" value="Simpan">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cl_image_upload_tag` is used to perform direct uploading from the browser to Cloudinary. When you submit the form you there is no file parameter sent to your backend and thus the `Cloudinary::Uploader::upload` call fails with the error `Missing required parameter - file`.

If you would like to upload the file from your backend then you need to replace the `cl_image_upload_tag` with a regular file input field element. Once a file is selected and the form submitted your backend can use the same code to upload the file to Cloudinary.

On the other hand, if would like to use `cl_image_upload_tag` then please see the direct uploading section of the Cloudinary documentation that describes setting this up.
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload#direct_upload_file_tag